# Docking station for both USB 3 and USB C?

Tags: multiple-monitors, usb-3, docking-station, usb-c, docking

Does anybody know if I install a USB type C for my older [ASRock 970 Pro3 R2.0](https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/970%20pro3%20r2.0/)?

I want my desktop to connect with a docking station, so I can easily switch between my working laptop and personal desktop.

If a USB type C can not be installed on my current motherboard, is it then possible to use an adapter for USB type C -> USB 3.0 and still be able to use this setup with two monitors, keyboard, mouse etc.?

Or do you have any other ideas how to make this work?

Please look at the setup here:

[image: Link to image of setup]

Comment: Just get a USB C PCI card. [Tons of them exist](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=USB+C+PCI+card&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and should work fine.

Comment: What about my graphic from my dedicated graphic card. Will that be transferen to the docking station through the PCI slot / motherboard?